# How to update constraints dynamically?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have three `UIButton`, I have created programmatically constraints, at some condition i am removing one of `UIButton` as `button.removeFromSuperview()` & rest of two button will set constraints as per priorities.
Issue is when i am removing one `UIButton`(buttonWink) then as of viewLifeCycle `viewWillLayoutSubviews` will called & App crashes in below line

```
 buttonWink.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Ofcourse  because buttonWink is removed from superview however we can check before setting constraints as

```
  if buttonWink != nil {
        buttonWink.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      }
```

But by checking nil for every button will make code lengthy, is there any way of doing the same? i will really appreciate friends.

Output -

[image]

Here i am attaching my tried full code.

```
import UIKit
class MasterViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonMessage : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonLike : UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonWink : UIButton!
    @IBAction func tapsOnLike(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    @IBAction func tapsOnWink(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    @IBAction func tapsOnNextButton(){
        let vc = DetailViewController(nibName: "DetailViewController", bundle: nil)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       setConstraints()
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
       // setConstraints()
    }
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        //setConstraints()
    }
    func setConstraints() {

        if buttonMessage != nil {
            buttonMessage?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
            buttonLike?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            buttonWink?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        //Constraints for Message button

        let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonMessage, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8)
        leading.isActive = true

        let trailingToSuperView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonMessage, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -8)

        trailingToSuperView.priority = 998
        trailingToSuperView.isActive = true

        let bottomToSuperView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonMessage, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8)
        bottomToSuperView.isActive = true


        let trailingToWink = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonMessage, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buttonWink, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: -8)
        trailingToWink.priority = 999
        trailingToWink.isActive = true

        let leadingToLike = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonMessage, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buttonLike, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8)
        leadingToLike.isActive = true

        let alignBottomToWink = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonMessage, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buttonWink, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        alignBottomToWink.isActive = true

        let alignBottomToLike = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonMessage, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buttonLike, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        alignBottomToLike.isActive = true


        let equalWidthToWink = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonMessage, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buttonWink, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        equalWidthToWink.isActive = true


        let equalWidthToLike = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonMessage, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buttonLike, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        equalWidthToLike.isActive = true

        //Constraints for like button
        let trailingLikeToSuperView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonLike, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -8)
        trailingLikeToSuperView.priority = 999
        trailingLikeToSuperView.isActive = true
        let leadingToWink = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonLike, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buttonWink, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8)
        leadingToWink.isActive = true


        //Constraints for Wink button
        let trailingWinkToSuperView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonWink, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -8)
        trailingWinkToSuperView.isActive = true

    }

}
```

Comment: `buttonWink?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: @dan what about `let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonMessage, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8)` ?

Comment: Why remove the button? Just hide it. If your constraints are set up correctly, they'll automatically adjust.

Comment: @dfd by removing the `UIButton` i am setting new constraints with two button, it's mandatory.

Comment: Then move your constraints related to each button into separate arrays (if needed) of `NSLayoutConstraint`, and activate/deactivate as needed.

Comment: I understand but thing is `viewWillLayoutSubviews` definately invokes after removing one of button.  & Constraints are updating according to priorities.

Comment: Probably best **not** to add / remove constraints in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` as that function is called multiple times. Maybe try describing in a bit more detail exactly what you are trying to *do*.

Comment: I would agree with @DonMag, most of the times you don't need to remove buttons, all you need is to set their width and/or height to zero. Frequently you can put them in a container view and "do things".  You should probably try and describe the problem graphically. At the same time remember that recalculating the layout is the computationally most intensive task in the rendering cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added `UIStackView` & it's too easy,
Three buttons are added in horizontal stack view with 8 points spacing & added three constraints to stack view as `leading`, `trailing` & `bottom` to `superview`

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
@IBAction func tapsOnLikeInStack(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isHidden = true
}
@IBAction func tapsOnWinkInStack(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isHidden = true
}

func constraintsForStackView(){
    stackView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.spacing = 8
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.alignment = .fill

    let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8)
    leading.isActive = true
    let trailingToSuperView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -8)
    trailingToSuperView.isActive = true
    let bottomToSuperView = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -120)
    bottomToSuperView.isActive = true
}
```

Comment: That is much more elegant, good job! I would select your answer as the best answer so others looking for a similar solution will quickly find this :)

Answer (score 5):

Just FYI -

simply use a stack view for this.

It is incredibly easy: it's why Apple finally added a stack concept a couple yrs ago.

Comment: I agree with you, `Stackview` is incredible. please see my edited Question, is that good way to put code in `viewDidLoad` for constraints? however if i am using `stackView` i am sure we have to add constraints for buttons.

Comment: If you use a `UIStackView`, you won't need any constraints on the buttons. You only need constraints on the stack view, and you can add them in your storyboard. Don't remove the buttons from the superview. Just set their `hidden` property to `true`. The stack view will automatically adjust the size of the visible buttons to fill the space left by the hidden buttons.

Comment: @robmayoff alright, got it, what you say about put constraint in `viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: What about it? You wrote a lot of code that you could delete if you used a stack view, and you didn't use the methods Apple added in iOS 8 and iOS 9 that are much shorter. At a minimum you should watch the “Mysteries of Auto Layout” videos from WWDC 2015.

Answer (score 0):

as far as your `viewWillLayoutSubviews` code put your buttons into an array to use:

```
for btn in buttons {
    if (btn.superview != nil) {
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

and if you want to change the constraints for the buttons still in the view, give them identifiers when you create the constraints:

```
for btn in buttons {
    if btn.superview != nil {
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        for constraint in btn.constraints {
            switch constraint.identifier {
                case "winkBtnTrailing":
                    //do stuff like constraint = new layout constraint
                    //or constraint.firstItem = *new first Item to base trailing on*
                    break
                default: 
                    //don't do stuff?
                    break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just as a FYI using `button.removeFromSuperview()` doesn't set that button to nil, it just removes it from the view you called `.addSubview(button)` on